# Menu and submenu python

Tags: python, loops, recursion, while-loop, bioinformatics

How can I return from a sub menu to a main menu?
Also I want to keep the data generated in the submenu.

Main menu:

```
1. Load data
2. Filter data
3. Display statistics
4. Generate plots
5. Quit
```

On option 2 I have a submenu:

```
1. S. enterica
2. B. cereus
3. Listeria
4. B. thermosphacta
5. Quit
```

```
def mainMenu():  
    menuItems = np.array(["Load data", "Filter data", "Display statistics", "Generate plots", "Quit"])
    while True:
        choice = displayMenu(menuItems)
        if choice == 1:
            filename = input("Please enter filename: ")
            data = dataLoad(filename)
        elif choice == 2:
            menuItems = np.array(["S. enterica", "B. cereus", "Listeria", "B. thermosphacta", "Quit"])
            while True: 
                choice = displayMenu(menuItems)
                if choice == 1:
                    data = data[data[:,2] == 1] # 1 - S. enterica
                elif choice == 2:    
                    data = data[data[:,2] == 2] # 2 - B. cereus
                elif choice == 3:   
                    data = data[data[:,2] == 3]  # 3 - Listeria
                elif choice == 4:    
                    data = data[data[:,2] == 4] # 4 - B. thermosphacta
                elif choice == 5:
                    return data
                continue
        if choice == 3:
            statistic = input("Please enter statistic: ")
            print (dataStatistics(data, statistic))
        elif choice == 4:
            dataPlot(data)
        elif choice == 5:
            break
```

Comment: Please explain in moire detail what you want, and how the posted code is related to it.

Comment: Thank you, I modified the code. I hope its more clear now. On 
'elif choice == 2:    
                    return data 
                continue' 
I want to return to the mainMenu().

Comment: If you substantially change your question, you may invalidate the effort of people who are worked up to *help you with your original question*. It's a good practice to change questions only by appending additional or correcting information, introducing them with terms as **"Edit:"** or **"Append:"**.

Comment: Thanks. I modified it to make it easier to understand. The essence and functions used were the same. Only the variables and length of the code were changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the break statement in the submenu and placed the menuItems inside the loops. This worked and data created in the submenu (subchoice) can be used in the mainMenu options 3 & 4.

```
import numpy as np
from displayMenu import *
from dataLoad import *
from dataStatistics import *
from dataPlot import *
from bFilter import *

def mainMenu():  
while True:
    menuItems = np.array(["Load data", "Filter data", "Display statistics",
                          "Generate plots", "Quit"])
    choice = displayMenu(menuItems)
    if choice == 1:
        filename = input("Please enter filename: ")
        data = dataLoad(filename)
    elif choice == 2:
        while True:
            menuItems = np.array(["S. enterica", "B. cereus", "Listeria", 
                                 "B. thermosphacta", "Back to main menu"])
            subchoice = displayMenu(menuItems)
            if subchoice in (1, 2, 3, 4):
                data = data[data[:,2] == subchoice]
            if subchoice == 5:
                break 
            continue
    elif choice == 3:
        statistic = input("Please enter statistic: ")
        print (dataStatistics(data, statistic))
    elif choice == 4:
        dataPlot(data)
    elif choice == 5:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
def mainMenu():  
    mainMenuItems = np.array(["Load data", "Filter data", "Display statistics", 
                              "Generate plots", "Quit"])
    subMenuItems  = np.array(["S. enterica", "B. cereus", "Listeria", 
                              "B. thermosphacta"])
    while True:
        choice = displayMenu(mainMenuItems)
        if choice == 1:
            filename = input("Please enter filename: ")
            data = dataLoad(filename)
        elif choice == 2:
            while True: 
                subchoice = displayMenu(subMenuItems)
                if subchoice in (1, 2, 3, 4):
                    data = data[data[:,2] == subchoice]
                    break 
                # The answer is not a correct one
                continue
        elif choice == 3:     # instead of if
            statistic = input("Please enter statistic: ")
            print (dataStatistics(data, statistic))
        elif choice == 4:
            dataPlot(data)
        elif choice == 5:
            break
```

You don´t need a "Quit" option in your submenu - you want to repeat the nested loop (the submenu) *only in the case of wrong answer* (other as 1, 2, 3 or 4).

No action is needed to save the contents of your `data` variable as all action you perform are inside of your `mainMenu()` function. But if you need it outside of your function, use the `return data` statement as the *very last* in your function, outside of any loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You improved the readability of my code. However the SOLUTION is MISSING. On the main menu on choice 1, there is one type of data and on the submenu there is other data. I do need a QUIT or return to the mainMenu () option. In your solution I'm trapped in the submenu loop.

Comment: Yes, it may *seems* to you that you are trapped in the nested loop, but in reality *your are "trapped" in the main loop*, because you used *the same name* (`menuItems`) in the main loop and the nested one, too - and the nested loop *overwrites the main menu with the nested menu*. I didn't noticed it at first. So I edited my answer, and now I use differnt names (`mainMenuItems` and `subMenuItems`).

Comment: You may vote up my answer if it was useful for you, even though you are not fully satisfied with it.